# password hashing / login

Tags: php

im creating a website that requires user authorisation to access some features. im currently working on how a user creates an account and how to utilise sessions to authorise their login. user information is stored in a MySQL table named user which likely includes a reference of username and passwords.

ive been reading up on password hashing/salt for security and wanted the input of some PHP masters, considering im still a rookie to the language.

ive written the following scripts :

```
define('SALT_LENGTH', 6);

function generateHash($plaintext, $salt==null){
    if($salt == null){
        $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
    else{
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }

    return $salt . sha1($salt . $plaintext);
}
?>
```

this is a function included to generate a hash with a salt.

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = generateHash($_POST['password']);
try{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare(INSERT INTO user VALUES (:username, :password, :location,     :email, :name);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
    $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username, 
                         ':password'=>$password, 
                         ':location'=>$location, 
                         ':email'=>$email, 
                         ':name'=>$name);
```

this is the important parts of the script to create an account

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    //if form was submitted

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = generateHash($_POST['password']);

    session_start();

    $user = 'root';
    $pass = null;
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=divebay;', $user, $pass);

    try{
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT username FROM user WHERE username =     :username AND password = :password');
        $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username,
                             ':password'=>$password);

        if($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo 'match';
        }
        else{
            echo 'nomatch';
        }
```

this is the login session script to lookup users in the database

my main question is does this hashing/salt look like it will work? im confused as to how a hash used to create an encryption in one instance (create acct) will be able to work with a hash created in a different instance. further, is the complexity of what im trying to create appropriate for a relatively simple software project that will likely never be properly deployed?

any other suggestions of where my scripts are wrong will be appreciated also (i need the criticism).

Comment: Don't roll your own unless it's for fun.  There are plenty of libraries that make this stupidly easy and secure.

Comment: By the way using an MVC architecture would be a plus !

Comment: Don't use MD5/SHA1! Use bcrypt.

Comment: @newfurniturey yer mate fair go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice to you is to look for a library/framework that does this for you. Many frameworks will automatically and correctly take care of this kind of thing under the hood for you, often including roles based authorization. Authentication and Authorization aren't immensely difficult to get right, but they're hard enough that you should try to avoid doing it yourself unless you're doing it as a learning exercise.

As for the correctness of your code, I think you need to use the salt matching the stored password on your account name to compare passwords. You should be looking up the password hash for the given username in the database, retrieving the salt from that password hash (which you correctly appended) then using the retrieved salt on the supplied password to get a hash. You then string compare the hash with the stored hash to authenticate.

I don't really know PHP well, but I'm sure that a library exists that will handle this for you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks wrong, when no salt is provided you take a random one that you do not store.

After an hashing you'll try to log your user, you'll hash the password provided, compute it's hash and check it against the one stored in database. If your hash can change with time, this is not a hash.

You have either to use a constant salt (perhaps a longer one than a six char long one), either to store the generated salt in the database. You HAVE TO be able to compute the exact same hash for the exact same input.

Answer (score 1):

As long as `generateHash` is called on both the password creation and password check when logging in, this hash will function properly due to the same output (assuming the same input).

However, as of right now, this does not seem to be the case. You will need to store the `$salt` (as it's randomly generated) in the database and retrieve it during the check.